# Nikon d3100 edited images not saved on SD card

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, cropping

I'm just a beginner as my husband has just bought me my first quality camera so please bear with me.

I have taken photos today at my sons nativity play and we were quite far away so I "trimmed" the images to get a closer image but the trimmed images are not saving on my SD card?? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi , Check this manual and Go to the Page no 29..http://nps.nikonimaging.com/technical_solutions/viewnx2_reference_manual/pdf/ViewNX2_RM_En_A4_01.pdf

Comment: That's the manual for the ViewNX software - what does that have to do with cropping in the camera?

Answer (score 1):

With in camera editing Nikon cameras ask if you want to save changes and you need to press "ok" to save the image, did this happen? The other thing that will sometimes happen is a new file is made and you might not be able to access it on your camera. If you connect the camera to your PC go to "Computer" or "My Computer" on your PC, open your camera there and see if there are multiple files, check each file to see if it was stored in another place that you cant view on the camera its self.